# Encode/Decode HttpPost UTF-8 Java

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8, httpclient

I am having troubles trying to send post data in utf8 format from the client to my server.

I have read a lot about this topic but I can´t find the solution. I am sure that I am missing something basic.

Here is my client code to make the post request

```
public static PostResponse post(String url, String data) {
        PostResponse response = new PostResponse();
        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

            // 3. set string to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(data);

            // 4. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 5. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return response;

    }
```

This is the code in my server side to receive the text in utf8 (Polish characters are not appearing, I am getting "?" instead.)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
            BufferedReader reader;
            reader = req.getReader();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            msg = gson.fromJson(reader, MsgChat.class); //String in the client was json
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
}
```

I wrote only the relevant code.

I would appreciate any help regarding this.
Thanks.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem. You should use this code:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8"));
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I see you should use `new StringEntity(data, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)`. By default it is `iso-8859-1`, `setHeader` is not correct way to set encoding as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try the addRequestHeader method of the HttpPost instead like

```
httpPost.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
```

as that is the recommended way of adding content type header to your request.